# Why this exception regarding elastic search occurs in Moqui?

Tags: elasticsearch, moqui

The exception looks like this.
[image: Elastic search exception]

I am not able to understand the cause for this exception. I tried restarting the server but still it keeps occurring again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ElasticSearch error and not something controlled by Moqui. I have seen this and based on my limited research it appears to happen when there are multiple ElasticSearch nodes running on the same network (in your case probably multiple Moqui nodes on the same network) and they seem to find the other nodes but not successfully sync up with them because they are not configured for it.

I haven't seen this cause any problems with anything else, so it seems annoying but safely ignored. There may be some ElasticSearch configuration that resolves this.

Comment: Thank you David for clarifying this issue.